# TSQL query to return most recent record based on another columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains a list of expiration dates for various companies. The table looks like the following:

```
ID  CompanyID  Expiration
--- ---------- ----------
1   1          2016-01-01
2   1          2015-01-01
3   2          2016-04-02
4   2          2015-04-02
5   3          2014-01-03
6   4          2015-04-09
7   5          2015-07-20
8   5          2016-05-01
```

I am trying to build a TSQL query that will return just the most recent record for every company (i.e. CompanyID).  Such as:

```
ID  CompanyID  Expiration
--- ---------- ----------
1   1          2016-01-01
3   2          2016-04-02
5   3          2014-01-03
6   4          2015-04-09
8   5          2016-05-01
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like there is a exact correlation between ID and Expiration.  If that is true, ie the later the Expiration the higher the ID, then you could simply pull `Max(ID)` and `Max(Expiration)` which are 1:1 and group by `CompanyID`:

```
Select max(ID), CompanyID, max(Expiration) from Table group by Company ID
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't realize the correlation between ID and Expiration.